# DataGridView Filtering Using TextBox (C#)

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview, textbox

I'm trying to filter my dgv using a textbox.

I've looked at several methods for filtering a dgv, and a good portion of the solutions involve dabbling in a database.

My program has a database, which is loaded onto the dgv at startup. I want to filter the dgv, preferably without touching the database.

As of right now, I have a filter, but its using the database. Furthermore, its using the SQLiteDataAdapter function to get the data into a datatable.

...Using the SQLiteDataAdapter function causes some big problems for my dgv, because it creates duplicate columns; which is why I read (DataReader) the data, instead of using the DataAdapter function.

This is my part of my code:

LOAD FORM:

```
            string qry = "SELECT * FROM table1";
            sqlcmd = new SQLiteCommand(qry, sqlconnection);
            sqlda = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
            dt = new DataTable();

            sqlda.SelectCommand = sqlcmd;
            sqlda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

TEXT CHANGED EVENT:

```
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Item LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
```

This code gets the job done, but like I said before, using SQLiteDataAdapter creates duplicate columns for me. **So how do I use just the dgv and textbox alone to filter data?**

(I've looked at several "solutions", none of which worked for me)
Here is the most common:
`((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "Item like'%" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%'";`

I get the error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Also tried using:

```
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = "Item like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: Basically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it - are you sure that your dataGridView has DataSource when you set its .`DefaultView.RowFilter` to some value?

Comment: Let's focus on the duplicate columns problem, since that really is the core issue here.  Do you have columns already in the grid before you attach the DataTable?

Comment: @EugenePodskal As soon as I include a datasource, I get the problem that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Try `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;` or remove the columns from the grid and have AutoGenerateColumns = true.

Comment: @LarsTech It works, no more duplicate columns...but now when I type things into the search box, the rows are empty:/ I know why this happens. It's because the "duplicate" columns are the ones that have the data in the rows. So when I execute `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt', the rows that are originally there that have READ the data from the database, for some reason get erased. The duplicate columns get pushed in and they're the ones holding data...so I put AutoGenerateColumns to false, the rows where the data is supposed to be, exist...but the data is doesn't. Hope that made sense.

Comment: @LarsTech Is there a way to use SQLiteDataAdapter to load data into existing columns like DataReader...because from what I've seen, it's not possible. Almost everybody uses DataAdapter. However, in my program, I need to be able to add new items (from another form) and manipulate the data, and so far I've been able to do that with DataReader.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  If you have AutoGenerateColumns set to false, then you have to match the grid column to the table field.  `dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "field name";`

Comment: Back to my original question...how can I filter the dgv without ever touching the database, by using a textbox?

Comment: What is the issue?  You said this yourself: `This code gets the job done,`  You are blaming the adapter for something that I don't understand.  It just fills your DataTable with data, then you use a DataView to filter it.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes, it gets the job done. But not the way I want it to lol. Hence, the reason why I only want to use the dgv and a textbox.

Comment: Is it possible to fill a datatable using DataReader?